# Why "npx create-react-app project-name" not working on GIT BASH but works on other terminal

Tags: reactjs, bash, git, create-react-app, git-bash

I have installed the `create-react-app` globally using `npm install -g create-react-app`, but whenever I try running the `npx create-react-app project-name` on GIT BASH, it gets stuck in

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

and would not continue. One time I waited for almost 30minutes just to ensure that maybe my internet is just slow, but no. When I ran the command on say, Windows PowerShell or Windows Command Prompt, it works fine and would show that it really is installing the react packages and finish installing in about 2-3 minutes on the same internet connection. So I don't understand why it doesn't work on my GIT BASH terminal. Any ideas? In my classmates desktop/laptop, their GIT BASH works installing `npx create-react-app` with no issues, so I don't understand why it doesn't work on mine?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And then run CRA(p):

```
npx create-react-app (project name)
```